# How can I bind to all items in a wpf ListBox and specify a converter?

Tags: wpf

I have specified that the content of a `ListBox` is a list of objects.

```
<telerik:RadListBox x:Name="listViewTakeOffConfigurations"  
ItemsSource="{Binding EstimateTakeoffService.EstimatingTakeOffConfigurations}" >
```

The `ItemTemplate` is set up like so:

```
<telerik:RadListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
       <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition />
              <ColumnDefinition />
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FontName}" />
           <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Sample" FontFamily="{Binding FontName}"  Foreground="{Binding Path=FontColour, Converter={StaticResource hexColorToBrushConverter}}" FontSize="{Binding Path=FontSize}"  FontStyle="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource estimatingTakeOffConfigurationToFontStyleConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"  VerticalAlignment="Centre" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
       </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
</telerik:RadListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I have a problem with the FontStyle in the second textbox. I want it to bind to every item in the listbox which would involve me setting up a binding like {binding}, but then that doesn't allow me to add a converter and so the fontstyle won't be set anyway.

Does anyone have any suggests?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide more infomration about what you want doing with the FontStyle? Where are we applying it to? And what should we be converting from (with the Converter)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add the element name to point it back to the listbox, (assuming that's what you are trying to do)

```
FontStyle="{Binding 
  ElementName=listViewTakeOffConfigurations, 
  Path=SelectedItem, 
  Converter={StaticResource estimatingTakeOffConfigurationToFontStyleConverter},
  Mode=OneWay}"
```

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately. I shouldn't need to include the selected item anyway, since I want it to apply to all items in the ItemSource of the ListBox

Comment: No, the SelectedItem is where it would come from. However it definitely appears that there is infomration missing here.

Comment: I have actually managed to answer my own question. I need to specify the path like path=., that is equivalent to not specifying the path, and allowed me to add the converter.

Comment: Then you can also not specify any path and it does the same thing. Its why `{Binding}` is valid. :-)